# Как логировать в unit test?

Tags: android, юнит-тесты

На текущий момент при Unit тестировании в приложении не отображаются логи стандартным способом (Log.*, Timber.*). В качестве костыля в App задаю 
новое кастомное дерево тимбера, которое выводит в консоль:

```
//...
OnCreate() {
//...
     Timber.plant(new UnitTestTree());
//...
}
//..

private static class UnitTestTree extends Timber.Tree {

        @Override
        public void i(String message, Object... args) {
            System.out.printf(message + "\n", args);
        }

        @Override
        protected void log(int priority, String tag, String message, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
}
```

Но из-за этого возникает некоторое неудобство - НЕ при тестировани приходится комментировать строку с инициализацией дерева, при тестировании - расскоментировать, что на мой взгляд странно.
Есть ли какой либо способ программно узнать - код запущен в качестве unit test (JUnit) или же это приложение запущено на эмуляторе/девайсе?

Comment: а что вы проверяете при помощи юнит тестов? так как похоже у вас они проверяют что-то не то.